# Image from cms for different screen densities

Tags: react-native

I am using an image from a cms:

```
    <Image
      resizeMode="cover"
      source={{ uri: data?.imageName }}
      PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator />}
      style={styles.imageStyle}
    />
```

How can I use a different image for different screen densities,  when the images are not bundled in the app?

Comment: This should be handled on the server-side, Some cloud providers like Cloudinary provide this feature out of the box - https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_adapt_website_images_to_retina_and_hidpi_devices

Comment: React Native provide `Dimension  API` - https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions, with that, you can get  device width and height and fetch corresponding images density